# How to use $concat with a $cond with MongoDB Java drivers

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to do something like this in Java :

```
           $concat: [
             "$$value",
             {
               $cond: {
                 if: { $eq: [ "$$value", "My hobbies include:" ] },
                 then: " ",
                 else: ", "
               }
             },
             "$$this"
           ]
```

Source : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#string-concatenation

So my version is :

```
    Document concat = new Document("$concat", Arrays.asList(
            "$$value",
            new Document("$cond", new Document()
                    .append("if", eq("$$value", ""))
                    .append("then", "")
                    .append("else", " - ")),
            "$$this.category"));
```

But it's not working, I have the error message "'Unrecognized expression '$$value'"

Any idea ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, but it's not exactly how I wanted to do (I have to use BsonDocument) :

```
    BsonArray eq = new BsonArray();
    eq.add(new BsonString("$$value"));
    eq.add(new BsonString(""));

    Document concat = new Document("$concat", Arrays.asList(
            new BsonString("$$value"),
            new BsonDocument("$cond", new BsonDocument()
                    .append("if", new BsonDocument("$eq", eq))
                    .append("then", new BsonString(""))
                    .append("else", new BsonString(" - "))),
            new BsonString("$$this.category")));
```